# B2B Orders Marked Fraud

Tags: order-status, credit-card, suspected-fraud, fraud

We have a B2B website and all our customers are approved to be on the site. No public or guest checkouts. Typically they all use credit cards. Some of the transactions are being marked as fraud. We don't know why.

Magento 2 - Fraud Protection is not enabled. I can't get the orders to go to a pending state or processing state. We have to call the customer and take everything over the phone which is causing delays and backing up customer service.

The credit cards are authorizing and nothing is wrong with the data from the merchant services. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The issue was that the price was rounded on 4 decimals instead of 2. So when the price was something like 49.5070 and was rounded, became 49.51. Due to different prices the transaction was reported as fraudulent.

Comment: Yes, this is what is happening. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804883/suspected-fraud-status-after-compeleting-the-payment-in-magento

Comment: How do I stop the rounding?